# Timeline, using foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, timeline

I am trying to plot an automated timeline with equidistant years on the axis, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\start{2010}; %Start year
\def\ende{2018};  %End year

\draw[->](0,0) -- (\textwidth, 0);
\foreach \j in {0,...,{\ende-\start}} {
({\j*{\textwidth/{\ende-\start}}},0) \node[rotate=45, left] {{\start+\j}};
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yet, I keep getting variations of:

[image]

As you can see, I have two problems:

`\start+\j` does not add up and the loop won't run. My weapon of choice was an excessive amount of `{}`-brackets. Thank your for your help :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following. It fixes your "not-calculations" (braces do not equal calculation) and wrong syntax for `\foreach`.

[image: timeline]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\start{2010} %Start year
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ende{2018}  %End year
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\differenz{\ende-\start}

\draw[->](0,0) -- (\textwidth, 0);
\foreach \j in {0,..., \differenz} {
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tmp{\j*\textwidth/\differenz}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\jahr{\start+\j}
    \draw (\tmp,0) node[rotate=45, left, yshift=-6pt] {\jahr};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you a lot. 

Where do I find documentation on both

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro and \pgfmathtruncatemacro ?

Comment: @EricScöerg In the TikZ manual (it is on CTAN). Please note that the documentation might not be beginner friendly at that point, but the easy rule is: `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` calculates and gives you the integer part and `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` gives you a length (such as a x coordinate).